# File corruption in de-serialization, how to prevent a crash?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, crash

I'am using boost graph library to work with graphs.
I use boost::serialization to write my graph to a file.

For testing purpose, I modifed the integrity of the file. Now my program just crashed all the time.
I was wondering is there any way to prevent the crash (boost::serialization doesn't throw exceptions).

And more generally for any type of file with no exception thrown in parsing, where all is supposed to be correct, is there a way too ?

Maybe the only solution is to write custom serialization/de-serialization functions with exception handling ?

Thank you !

Edit: There is a boost::archive::archive_exception when the all data is corrupted or the file is missing. But if only certain part of the file are changed, it crashes ...

Edit2: I should caught the input_stream_error exception, but I don't.

Comment: As far as I can tell, custom serialization/de-serialization functions are mandatory in any case and the only option is whether to put it into the class itself or to put it into `boost::serialization` namespace. Can you post example code where this is not necessary?

Comment: The whole idea of using the graph serialization proposed by the BGL is not to write custom functions.
My data structure is very simple: only structs with 1 int for Node and 1 double and 1 int for Edge.

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize that you are using BGL. I thought you were implementing a graph library yourself.

Answer (score 1):

A `boost::archive_exception` is also thrown in other situations than corruption of the whole data or missing file. See [Archive Exceptions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/exceptions.html) for details.